# Polling for process exit using Perl

Tags: windows, perl

I am automating some installation procedures using Perl. Now I wish to know when the installation procedure I fired has gotten finished. How do I do this? Since this is automation work, I cannot ask people to *fire some commands at a later point of time*. This functionality should be automatic. How do I do this on Windows?

Comment: The question is, what exactly are you waiting for? A process to finish, perhaps? If so, do you know the name or pid of the process?

Comment: @GregHewgill I am working on windows, so ya.. I would be waiting for a process to finish .. can you please tell me how i must check for a process termination on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greg Hewgill's answer addresses the underlying Windows API functions you need, but not how to use them in Perl.  You can use the [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aProcess) module for this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::Process;

Win32::Process::Create(
  my $process,
  'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe', # path of executable
  "notepad",                         # command line it sees
  0,                                 # don't inherit our handles
  NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,             # process creation flags
  "."                                # current directory for process
) or die $^E;

print "started\n";

$process->Wait(INFINITE);

print "done\n";

$process->GetExitCode(my $exitcode) or die $^E;

print "process exit code $exitcode\n";
```

`$process` can also be passed to the [Win32::IPC](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aIPC) functions `wait_any` and `wait_all` if you need to wait for more than one object at a time.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, use a handle to the process and call `WaitForSingleObject()` to find out when the process terminates. If you only have the process ID, you can use `OpenProcess()` to get a handle to it. (Of course, if you created the process yourself with `CreateProcess()`, you already have a handle to it.)